# Conditional statement to avoid concurrent Webclient IO thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, io

I am using a webclient to download a media file from my web server and save to isolated storage.

If you click a button it starts the download and save to Iso store process, but if you click the button while the file is downloading it tries to create a concurrent IO thread to download again and errors with webclient does not allow concurrent IO threads.

I want to write a conditional if statement to check if there is already a IO thread in being used but I'm not sure how I would do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just use a boolean to see if you started the download already? Either way it sounds like it would be better to actually *disable* the button in the UI after you start a download, and enable it again once it finishes or fails.

Your UI should be consistent with what users have the ability to do at a given time - letting them try something and then make them fail sounds like a frustrating user experience.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Good suggestion, I think that is the best option from a user perspective. I will use a boolean to collapse the button when download is in progress. Cheers